# Alternative to Date.to_time_in_current_zone as Rails 4.1 removed it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.1

In order to get the beginning of today in the current time zone, I had the following code:

```
Time.zone.today.to_time_in_current_zone
```

However, upgrading to Rails 4.1 caused an error as the `to_time_in_current_zone` method was removed. What should I use as an alternative? `Time.zone.today.to_time` gives me the beginning of the day in UTC time zone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `in_time_zone` instead.

```
Time.zone.today.in_time_zone
```

Till 4.0.2 `to_time_in_current_zone` was supported. See this [link](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/Date/to_time_in_current_zone) for more info.